# Unwritable file

Tags: bash, terminal, permissions

I'm trying to edit the terminal on my Pi and whenever I edit my terminal with the command `nano /boot/config.txt` this comes up:

```
nano /boot/config.txt unwritable
```

Whenever I try to exit and try to save I get an error message

```
[Error writing /boot/config.txt: Permission denied]
```

Comment: Add sudo, ‘sudo nano /boot/config.txt’

Answer (score 1):

When issuing your command, if permissions are denied, the easiest way to fix that is to run the command with root privileges.

Like this:

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

`sudo` basically let's the command after it do whatever it wants (like in your case, let `nano` write to `/boot/config.txt`), so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

You need root permission to edit system files.

This can be done with `sudo nano` but it is much better to use `sudoedit`

`sudoedit /boot/config.txt`